# How not to print Qt internal messages on console?

Tags: qt

I have a program that functionally works well, but it prints messages on console like:
**QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread error**

Is there a way to configurate it, so it does not print them anymore?

Regards

Comment: Yes, but as a non-answer, ideally you *fix* the issue, instead of hiding it. If that timer doesn't need to be started, then remove the starting code. If it needs to be started, you need to make it actually start: do it from the right thread (using signals&slots or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`).

Comment: This usually indicates a bug, though. So you likely have a problem, even if the program "works" well. I'm almost sure there's some undefined behavior somewhere. There are very few cases when those messages can be ignored, usually only when the object's thread got destroyed and the object is about to be destroyed itself. In such case, though, the information about the timer is leaked by Qt (it's a bug, but is triggered by a bug in user code). So, at the very minimum, this warning can indicate a memory leak (small one, thankfully), but it can also indicate worse. UB is not guaranteed to crash!

Comment: Wish Qt could add the variable/object name of `QObject` in the message, help to debug.

Comment: @Jiu Qt Creator has an option to break when `qWarning()` is called, so you can break and see the complete callstack when the warning is emitted.

Comment: @BenjaminT `qInstallMessageHandler`?

Comment: @Jiu I am talking about a Qt Creator option: "Tools > Options... > Debugger > GDB Extended > Stop when qWarning() is called". But yes, you can do everything using `qInstallMessageHandler()`.